# Combine 2 ajax calls into 1 callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension, callback

I'm building a Chrome extension and I need to combine 2 separate AJAX calls so that I have 1 callback on success. What is the best way to do that?

```
Auth.prototype.updateContact = function(id, contact_obj) {
  var self = this,
      contact_str = JSON.stringify(contact_obj);

  return new RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    self.authorize()
      .then(function() {
        $.ajax({
          type: "PUT",
          url: self.url + "contacts/" + id,
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          data: contact_str,
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(data) {
            resolve(data);
          },
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            var msg = "updateContact error: request: " + id + " " +
                  contact_str + " response: " + jqXHR.responseText +
                  " e=" + JSON.stringify(errorThrown);
            sendErrorBackground(msg);
            reject(jqXHR);
          }
        });
      });
  });
};

Auth.prototype.updateContactList = function(id, list_obj) {
  var self = this,
      list_str = JSON.stringify(list_obj);

  return new RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    self.authorize()
      .then(function() {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: self.url + "add_lists",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          data: list_str,
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(data) {
            resolve(data);
          },
          error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            var msg = "updateContactList error: request: " + id + " " +
                  list_str + " response: " + jqXHR.responseText +
                  " e=" + JSON.stringify(errorThrown);
            sendErrorBackground(msg);
            reject(jqXHR);
          }
        });
      });
  });
};
```

Attempt at using @Saar's suggestion

```
Auth.prototype.updateContact = function(id, contact_obj, list_obj) {
  var self = this,
      contact_str = JSON.stringify(contact_obj),
      list_str = JSON.stringify(list_obj);


  var promiseA = new RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        self.authorize().then(function() {
          $.ajax({
            type: "PUT",
            url: self.url + "contacts/" + id,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: contact_str,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
              return data
            }
          });
        });
      });

  var promiseB = new RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    self.authorize().then(function() {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: self.url + "add_lists",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          data: list_str,
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(data) {
            return data
          }
        });
      });
    });

  $.when(promiseA, promiseB).then(function(resultA, resultB) {
    console.log(resultB);
  });
};
```

Comment: you are already using promises and jQuery, just use `$.when(promiseA,promiseB).then(function(resultA,resultB){//do something here});`

Comment: I read about using `$.when` but promises are something I'm not terribly familiar with. I edited my post to include my best attempt at your solution but the console is only logging the promise object, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your using RSVP promises then you need to use "all"

```
Auth.prototype.updateContact = function (id, contact_obj, list_obj) {
    var self = this,
        contact_str = JSON.stringify(contact_obj),
        list_str = JSON.stringify(list_obj);


    var promiseA = new RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        self.authorize().then(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "PUT",
                url: self.url + "contacts/" + id,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: contact_str,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    return data
                }
            });
        });
    });

    var promiseB = new RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        self.authorize().then(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: self.url + "add_lists",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: list_str,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    return data
                }
            });
        });
    });


    var promises = [promiseA, promiseB];

    RSVP.all(promises).then(function (results) {
        // results contains an array of results for the given promises
        console.log(results);
    }).catch(function (reason) {
        // if any of the promises fails.
    });
};
```

Comment: I'm getting an error - `Error in event handler for runtime.onMessage: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`. It might be breaking somewhere else in the extension though. I'll do some investigating, thanks for your help.

Comment: If you can supply a fiddle I will help you.gladly

Comment: Thanks but it would probably take too long to setup a fiddle. If I figure it I'll come back and update this. I think you pointed me in the right direction, its returning an object from each call now, its probably just returning unexpected results somewhere else thats breaking it.

Comment: Just for the record it was unexpected results elsewhere in the ext and I wasn't returning the results in `RSVP.all` correctly. Thanks again for the help.